# Find n-th convergent of continued fraction

Tags: convergence-divergence, continued-fractions, pell-type-equations

> Let **d = 7**. **√7** has a periodic continued fraction of the form:
>   **[2, (1, 1, 1, 4)]**. So **r= 4** (r is the period). Notice that r is even.

*After a lot of research I found out that:*

If period is even, then **x<sub>1</sub> = h<sub>nr-1</sub>** and **y<sub>1</sub> = k<sub>nr-1</sub> , n = 1,3,5,7 ...** where h<sub>n</sub>/k<sub>n</sub> are the convergents of the expansion of √7 and x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub> the minimal solution of Pell's equation, **x<sup>2</sup> - 7y<sup>2</sup> = 1**.

If period is odd, then **x<sub>1</sub> = h<sub>nr-1</sub>** and **y<sub>1</sub> = k<sub>nr-1</sub> , n = 2,4,6,8 ...**

Eg. For d = 7, period is even (=4) so **x<sub>1</sub> = h<sub>1*4-1</sub> = h<sub>3</sub>** and **y<sub>1</sub> = k<sub>1*4-1</sub> = k<sub>3</sub>**. That means the solution (x1, y1) can be obtained by the 3<sup>rd</sup> convergent of **√7**.

x<sub>1</sub> can be found very easily from a mathematical aspect.

**1<sup>st</sup> convergent: 2 + 1 / 1 = (2 * 1 + 1) / 1 = 3/1. So h<sub>1</sub> = 3 and k<sub>1</sub> = 1.**

**2<sup>nd</sup> convergent: 2 + 1 / (1 + 1 / 1) = 2 + 1 / (1 + 1) = 2 + 1 / 2 = (2 * 2 + 1) / 2 = 5/2 .
So h<sub>2</sub> = 5 and k<sub>2</sub> = 2.**

**3<sup>rd</sup> convergent: With the same way we prove that h<sub>3</sub> = 8 and k<sub>3</sub> = 3.**

So **x<sub>1</sub> = h<sub>3</sub> = 8 and y1 = k<sub>3</sub> = 3**.

The mathematical way is pretty straight-forward.

> I am really stuck trying to implement an algorithm which calculates h<sub>n</sub> and k<sub>n</sub>.

- How can I implement the calculation of the n-th convergent when the sequence **[2, (1, 1, 1, 4)]** is known ?

Answer (score 3):

I found solution to my problem from this paper: https://www.math.ru.nl/~bosma/Students/CF.pdf

You can calculate any convergent from this formula: **p<sub>n</sub>/q<sub>n</sub> = (a<sub>n</sub> * p<sub>n-1</sub> + p<sub>n-2</sub>) / (a<sub>n</sub> * q<sub>n-1</sub> + q<sub>n-2</sub>)**

Answer (score 2):

The simple continued fraction convergents basically can be calculated like a 2x2 matrix product of the coefficients in the following form.
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
c_1 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \cdot ... \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{n-1} & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
c_n & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
p_n & p_{n-1}\\
q_n & q_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}